# L2TP/IPSec using srongswan in ubuntu

Tags: vpn, ipsec, l2tp

I'm using `strongswan` on ubuntu 16.04 to connect to a thirdparty L2TP/IPSec VPN.

They provided me a profile file like this:

```
VPN connection IP : X.X.X.X

IPSEC Authentication : ---------------------
IPSEC Preshared key : SOME^"TH!NG$
L2TP authentication : 
username :  USER
password :  PASS

IPSEC Phase 1 Proposal----------------------
encryption 3DES     Authentication SHA1
encryption AES192   Authentication SHA1
encryption AES256   Authentication MD5
Diffie-Hellman Group 2
Key lifetime (seconds) 86400

IPSEC Phase 2 Proposal----------------------
Local Address 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0
Remote Address 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0
encryption 3DES     Authentication SHA1
encryption AES192   Authentication SHA1
encryption AES256   Authentication MD5
Key lifetime (seconds) 86400
```

I have created /etc/ipsec.conf like this:

```
config setup
  # strictcrlpolicy=yes
  # uniqueids = no

conn %default
  ikelifetime=60m
  keylife=20m
  rekeymargin=3m
  keyingtries=1
  keyexchange=ikev1
  authby=secret
  ike=3des-sha1,AES192-sha1,aes256-md5,modp1024!
  esp=3des-sha1,AES192-sha1,aes256-md5!

conn myvpn
  keyexchange=ikev1
  left=MY.IP.ADD.RESS
  auto=add
  authby=secret
  type=transport
  leftprotoport=17/1701
  rightprotoport=17/1701
  right=X.X.X.X
```

and /etc/ipsec.secrets like:

```
# empty line
MY.IP.ADD.RES X.X.X.X : PSK 'SOME^"TH!NG$'
```

(my ip address: MY.IP.ADD.RES and remote server: X.X.X.X)

`$ sudo ipsec up myvpn` results like below:

```
initiating Main Mode IKE_SA myvpn[2] to X.X.X.X
generating ID_PROT request 0 [ SA V V V V ]
sending packet: from MY.IP.ADD.RES[500] to X.X.X.X[500] (204 bytes)
sending retransmit 1 of request message ID 0, seq 1
sending packet: from MY.IP.ADD.RES[500] to X.X.X.X[500] (204 bytes)
sending retransmit 2 of request message ID 0, seq 1
```

How I should find out what is wrong with my config file?

Is `ike` or `esp` wrong or mismatch with given profile?

I'm new to this section, beside my question, any directions to docs, helpful blogs or informations about given profile might help me.

Comment: Could you solve the problem finally?

Comment: @ilyasJumadurdyew yeah, and thank you for the mention. I posted a fix as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was my fault that I didn't match `ike` (with `IPSEC Phase 1 Proposal`) and `esp` (with `IPSEC Phase 2 Proposal`) exactly with given VPN profile:

[Full list of Cipher Suites available for strongswan IKEv2 is available here](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/IKEv2CipherSuites).

My corrected `/etc/ipsec.conf` is:

```
config setup

conn %default
  ikelifetime=86400s
  keylife=86400s
  rekeymargin=3m
  keyingtries=1
  keyexchange=ikev1
  authby=secret
  ike=3des-sha1,AES192-sha1,aes256-md5,modp1024!
  esp=3des-sha1,AES192-sha1,aes256-md5!

conn myvpn
  # our public ip
  left=MY.IP.ADD.RES
  auto=add
  authby=secret
  # phase 1
  ike=3des-sha1-modp1024,aes192-sha1-modp1024,aes256-md5-modp1024
  # phase 2
  esp=3des-sha1,aes192-sha1,aes256-md5
  type=transport
  leftprotoport=17/1701
  rightprotoport=17/1701
  # remote VPN ip
  right=X.X.X.X
```

[`ipsec.conf` documentation reference](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/ConnSection)

Comment: i think the line `esp=3des-sha1,aes192-sha1,aes256-mp5` should actually be `esp=3des-sha1,aes192-sha1,aes256-md5` (change the `p` to a `d`)